# How to find the column index of radio button in jquery data table

Tags: jquery, datatables

Hi I want to know the column index which radio button has selected in data table.

Here is my code for data table:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    table = $('#ReportTable').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "ajax": {
            url: 'ajax_call.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                action: 'loadEmailData'
            }
        },
        "columnDefs": [{
                "aTargets": [0],
                "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
                    id = full[3];
                    var returnval = "<td><input type='radio' name='chkNew" + id + "'  class='call-checkbox' value=" + id + "  id=\"chkNew'" + id + "'\" /></td>";
                    return returnval;
                }

            }, {
                "aTargets": [1],
                "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
                    id = full[3];
                    var returnval = "<td><input type='radio' name='chkNew" + id + "'   class='call-checkbox'  value=" + id + "  id=\"chkSubmit'" + id + "'\" /></td>";
                    return returnval;
                }

            }, {
                "aTargets": [2],
                "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
                    id = full[3];
                    var returnval = "<td><input type='radio' name='chkNew" + id + "' class='call-checkbox' value=" + id + " id=\"chkDeploy'" + id + "'\"/></td>";
                    return returnval;
                }

            }

        ]
    });
});
```

Here is function to get the selected column index and id of selected column: Here it is alert the index of column like 0,1. If I clicked 1st and 3rd column also it is alert as 0,1, It should alert 0,2

```
rowcollection.each(function(index,elem){
    var checkbox_value = $(elem).val(),
        globalindex = $(this).closest('tr')find('input[type="radio"]').index(this);

    arr[globalindex]=checkbox_value;

    alert(globalindex);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can trigger `change` event on radio button using `.delegate`:

```
$( "#ReportTable" ).delegate("input[type='radio']", "change", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $this.val();
    // do sth
});
```

> .delegate()
>
> Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the
>   selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root
>   elements. [More](http://jqapi.com/#p=delegate)

Comment: What is "change"  here.

Comment: I correct the answer. `.change` event trigers whenever radio button selected.

Comment: Hi above solution is displaying the value of clicked radio button, But I want column index number whether 0th,1st,2nd column..